# Issue while encoding a string

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding

I'm developing an application where at some point i need an encoded stream of bytes based on the given user output.

Something like

```
Encoding sysEncode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
byte[] dataToEncrypt = sysEncode.GetBytes(m_oStrActivation);
```

However when i extract the string from the byte stream i get the encrypted string as

```
W?????e?????W?X????;??2????W???????@
```

Is there any way(type of Encoding/equivalent) i can restrict these question marks and allow only plain scrambled alphanumeric characters ?

Answer (score 1):

From `m_oStrActivation` and you mentioning "encryption" I assume that you're writing some kind of activation/licensing code. If this is the case, you're doing it wrong. A correct way to do this is to use a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) over your activation data.

You can then transform this string into Base64 string using [Convert.ToBase64String()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) method.

Comment: To be clear for constantlearner - the `System.Text.Encoding` namespace has nothing to do with encryption - it's for dealing with character set code pages.